# How to detect end of avaliable movement of mechanism connected to a stepper motor, without external detectors?

Tags: stepper-motor, motion

I have access to (not quite working) 3D printer. It has no endstops, no switches that would detect extreme positions of head or table. I know this because I was there when it was assembled. All cables are accounted for. 4 for each Nema 17 step motor, 2 x 2 for thermistors, 6 x 2 for heaters and that's all.

Yet, despite the lack of any sensors, printer can move head to extreme right or left, can move table to the bottom or to the top and so on. And motors don't get hot. It just goes to the end and then moves back a fraction of millimeter and stops.

So, how could they do it? What's the "signal" of end of possible movement, when all we got to work with is 4 cables that power said motor? Of course in my projects I plan to use proper endstops, but in case they fail, this would be a welcomed backup mechanism.

To clarify:  When we first assembled this thing, it didn't crash to the side, and head was at pretty random position then. Or even if it was a crash, printer apparently somehow got to know about it, because now it has no problems with positioning.

Comment: Can you move your hand close to your face without touching it or watching it? The printer head knows how far it has moved and how big the table is. If if lost that information at some point and was not zeroed, it would crash into the side.

Comment: @Samuel it didn't when we first assembled it, and head was at pretty random position then. Or even if it was crash, printer somehow got to know about it...

Comment: Then it possibly has absolute encoders. It gets to know about it by zeroing it.

Comment: @Samuel I'll try to read about these "absolute encoders". And just by the way, human body *does* have [sensors for joints angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprioception). Humans that have them damaged can not move hand close to their face and not to slap themselves without looking.

Comment: Exactly my point, no end-stops required for most of us, we have absolute encoders in our joints.

Comment: Another method of sensing such extreme loads is to measure a current. When there is no possibility to make move at the end of axis (and driver still fed current to the motor) the torque increase abnormally and the current also increase a few times.

Comment: @lustful-rat wasn't it what transistor's answer indicated?

Comment: @Mołot Something like this, but I think about more sophisticated controllers, like ones used in the best CNC machines and assembly robots, where steering computer is able to detect even small but unexpected changes in torque, caused e.g. by body of rash operator ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stepper motors seldom use encoders. As you suspect, they normally run a homing routine, reset a counter to zero and keep track of the steps from then on. If you stall the mechanism the controller loses track and everything from there on will be offset.

The [ST dSPIN L6470](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00255075.pdf), for example, states,

> The L6470 device, realized in analog mixed  signal technology, is an
> advanced fully integrated  solution suitable for dr iving two-phase
> bipolar  stepper motors with microstepping. It integrates  a dual low
> R DS(on)  DMOS full bridge with all of the  power switches equipped
> with an accurate on- chip current sensing circuitry suitable for non-
> dissipative current c ontrol and overcurrent  protection. Thanks to a
> unique control system,  a true 1/128 steps resolution is achieved. The
> digital control core can generate user defined  motion profiles with
> acceleration, deceleration,  speed or target position, easily
> programmed  through a dedicated registers set. All commands  and data
> registers, incl uding those used to set  analogue values (i.e. current
> control value,  current protection trip  point, deadtime, PWM
> frequency, etc.) are sent through a standard  5-Mbit/s SPI. A very
> rich set of protections  (thermal, low bus voltage, overcurrent, **motor
> stall**) allows the design of a fully protected  application, as
> required by the most demanding  motor control applications.

On page 35 of the data sheet we read,

> **Sensorless stall detection**
>
> Depending on motor speed and load angle
> characteristics, the L6470 offers a motor stall  condition detection
> using a programmable current comparator. When a stall event occurs,
> the respective fl ag (STEP_LOSS_A or ST EP_LOSS_B) is forced  low
> until a GetStaus command or a system reset occurs (see  Section 9.2.20
> on page 66).

Enjoy reading!

Comment: That seems to be it. And sounds more probable than encoders.